# Installing Compcert-2.6 on 64bit Mac

Tags: ocaml, opam, ocamlfind, menhir

I got the following error when compiling compcert 2.6 on 64bit macos

```
$./configure ia32-macosx
...
$make
...
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Makefile.extr ccomp
ocamlfind: Package `menhirLib' not found
OCAMLOPT driver/Version.ml
ocamlopt.opt: unknown option '-3'.
Usage: ocamlopt <options> <files>
Options are:
  ...
make[2]: *** [driver/Version.cmx] Error 2
make[1]: *** [ccomp] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I installed both coq and menhir thru opam but somehow ocamlfind cannot find "menhirlib".

Versions Coq 8.4.pl6; Ocaml 4.02.2; opam 1.2.2; Menhir  20160303

Answer (score 1):

OPAM package `menhir.20160303` does not install `META` file for `menhirLib`.  You should file a bug report at https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/

For a workaround, you can install Menhir by hand to make sure `menhirLib` is installed properly. (Never tried by myself though.)